# SQL Replace or Insert Into Syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

I cannot figure out what is wrong. My query looks like this:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO lang (name, string, lang) VALUES ('PAGE_TITLE', 'Page Title', 'en')
```

And this is where I execute that query:

```
foreach($lang_fields as $field){
    $update = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO lang (name, string, lang) 
            VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $field)."', 
                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST[$field])."', 
                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lang_load'])."')";
    echo $update;
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, $update)
        or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

And this is the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR REPLACE INTO lang (name, string, lang) VALUES ('PAGE_TITLE', 'P' at line 1

Comment: There is no `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO` they are separate statements http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does not support any `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO` syntax that I've seen. You may be looking for something like `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. In your example it may look like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (name, string, lang) VALUES (param1, param2, param3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = param1, string = param2, lang = param3;
```

More information can be found in the documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html

An example of this can be found using this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/253277/1).

Comment: Yes, I was looking at SQLite resources, it seems that MySQL does not support this. Thank you.

Comment: @TemporaryName no problem. If this answer works for you, feel free to upvote and accept the answer. If you have trouble getting it working just ask.

Comment: I'm working on implementing this. The code just inserted 2000 rows into my table, it probably didn't detect the duplicate key. Any idea why?

Comment: Which column is your key? Are you sure there are duplicates?

Comment: Totally sure, it was obvious that the rows had just been duplicated. I just added a key (auto_increment id, int (100)), do I just have to add it to the INSERT INTO?

Comment: Yeah, because it's auto increment, if you don't specify it in the fields, it will just add a new row. It never saw that there was a duplicate, if that makes sense.

Comment: It does, thank you! Would UPDATE target the correct row without a "WHERE id = '$id'"? If I have to add that, how would I find the id of the row with name = $name and lang = $lang?

Comment: I think the `UPDATE` will target the same row, because it will recognize that the id matches and that's how it determines the duplicate key you've specified. I can try and verify that for you, but I suspect that's the case.

Comment: @TemporaryName Here is a visual example that works, so you can see complete valid syntax: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/253277/1

Comment: I don't think this would work in my example and I am too afraid to try it out, actually. You see, the only unique field in my table is id, which is auto incremented, if I use INSERT INTO it will probably try to create a new one if I don't specify an id. The only other way to find a row which is unique is to search for it with WHERE lang = $lang and name = $name.

Comment: I think I saw an example where it was something like this `... VALUES ((SELECT id FROM lang WHERE x = y and y = x), param2, param3) ...`. Could I use something like that here?

Comment: You can alter the table to add a key, if you want. You can say each (lang, name) combination is a key, but be careful that there may already be duplicate (lang, name) pairs.

Comment: @TemporaryName I'm not sure if that's valid syntax, but you can try it. Build an SQL Fiddle example with sample data, or use the one that I linked to you, and test it with your actual database design until you get a query that does what you'd expect, then run it on the real data.

Comment: I solved it with your answer and a bit more php to get the id.