# insert on duplicate key update for two values?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

My `save_list` table contains three columns:

```
id, user_id, item_id
```

Query

```
INSERT INTO save_list (user_id, item_id) VALUES (?,?)
```

How can I use `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to update the row if both `user_id` and `item_id` exist?

Working code

```
INSERT INTO save_list (user_id, item_id) VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id = ?, item_id = ?
```

Comment: This question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383503/on-duplicate-key-update-same-as-insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a unique composite key across them both

```
ALTER TABLE tblName ADD UNIQUE unique_index777 (user_id,item_id);
```

Comment: OK ... added it, but how would I use that?

Comment: Once you've added that, you can use `INSERT INTO .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. I just gave an answer on that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277671/sql-replace-or-insert-into-syntax-error/31277803#31277803) which will have links to the documentation for you and such.

Comment: `$q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO save_list (user_id, item_id) VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE");` Like this?

Comment: @DrewPierce didn't mean to steal the thunder from your answer, but I gave that one so recently that I had everything fresh in my mind haha.

Comment: I don't have much thunder @McAdam331

Answer (score 0):

You need to have these 2 fields defined as a composite key for the update to work.

```
INSERT INTO foo_table(user_id, item_id, description) ft values (a,b,desc)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ft.description=desc
```

Should do the trick